# PHP - Inheritable copy method

Tags: php, function, oop, inheritance, copy

here is my situation : 
I have a class that is inherited by a dozen of others, in this class I have a copy method which returns a copy of itself. 
I can use this method in the inheriting class but, obviously, the method always return an instance of the super class, not the one which inherit from it. 
**I would like my copy method to return an instance of the ihneriting class.**

*BaseEntity.php :*

```
class BaseEntity
{
    protected $id;
    protected $name;
    protected $active;
    protected $deleted;

    // ...

    public function copy()
    {
        $copy = new BaseEntity();

        $copy->id = $this->id;
        $copy->name = $this->name;
        $copy->active = $this->active;
        $copy->deleted = $this->deleted;

        return $copy;
    }
}
```

*User.php :*

```
class User extends BaseEntity
{
    // ...
    // Properties are the same as BaseEntity, there is just more methods. 
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `clone`?

Comment: Then you need to inherit the copy() method in `User` class and add your logic there.

Comment: `$copy = new get_class($this)` try this instead of `$copy = new BaseEntity();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more way to achieve what you want:

```
<?php
class BaseEntity
{
    protected $id;

    public function copy()
    {
        $classname = get_class($this);
        $copy = new $classname;

        return $copy;
    }
}
class Test extends BaseEntity
{

}

$test = new Test;
$item = $test->copy();
var_dump($item); // object(Test)
```

Comment: Eventually in my situation I rather use this than the __clone() overloading.

Answer (score 1):

I see two ways of doing this:

1. using `clone` - it will make a shallow copy of your object
2. using `static` for creating a new object

   ```
   <?php

   class BaseEntity {
       public function copy() {
           return new static;
       }
   }

   class User extends BaseEntity {

   }

   $user = new User;
   var_dump($user->copy());
   ```

Result of this code: https://3v4l.org/2naQI

Comment: Could you tell me a bit more about this `return new static` ?

Comment: TL;DR Late static binding - https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php PHP docs describe it quite well :)

Comment: I don't see how to use `return new static`to make a copy, as it is it just return a new instance of the class the copy is called on.

Comment: `new static` won't do a full copy. It simply will allow you to create a new instance of the class from which context `copy()` was called. Other users posted solutions like `new get_class($this);` it's more fancy solution.

To do a copy use `clone`. Remember that it will make shallow copy - it means that objects assigned to attributes will by copied by reference.

Comment: Okay it is what I understood. Thanks for the help.